# HTML5 Video only loads after page is accessed through link in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video, loading

I run a wordpress website where the front page displays a HTML5 video which loads and autoplays in a loop, here is the code:

```
<video class="primary-video-bg" autoplay loop preload="none">
    <source data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/45_Second_Advert.webm" media="(min-width: 640px)" src="wp-content/uploads/2018/01/45_Second_Advert.webm">
    <source data-src="wp-content/uploads/2018/01/45-Second-Advert.mp4" media="(min-width: 640px)" src="wp-content/uploads/2018/01/45-Second-Advert.mp4">
</video>
```

Everything was fine up to yesterday when we updated our theme. Since then, on Chrome, if the website is accessed directly through the address bar, the video never loads. However, if the same page is accessed via clicking a link from anywhere, then the video loads perfectly. it only does this on Chrome. I would really appreciate if you could help me find a solution to this, as I am a bit lost as to what could be the cause.

Comment: Actually found the solution through this article: https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/09/google-chrome-block-auto-play-video/
It's a new Google policy, just had to mute the video.